# Set empty namespace to a DataContract

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wsdl, datacontract

I use a DataContract with an empty namespace

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]    
    public class crearCuentaPorCobrarRq
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 0)]
        public InfoRequest infoRequest { get; set; }
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
        public CuentaCobrar[] cuentasCobrar { get; set; }
    }
```

But unfortunatelly I obtain a wsdl like this:

```
<b:crearCuentaPorCobrarRq>
    <infoRequest></infoRequest>
    <cuentasCobrar></cuentasCobrar>
</b:crearCuentaPorCobrarRq>
```

Please forget the origin of b:, the question is that [DataContract(Namespace = "")] only delete in the DataMember the namespace and I want to quit in the DataContract too, such like this:

```
<crearCuentaPorCobrarRq>
    <infoRequest></infoRequest>
    <cuentasCobrar></cuentasCobrar>
</crearCuentaPorCobrarRq>
```

crearCuentaPorCobrar is an OperationContract method that is declared in a ServiceContract called: that has a namespace "com.lsc";. The idea is that crearCuentaPorCobrar maintains the prefix com but its parameters crearCuentaPorCobrarRq in the OperationContract changes:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "com.lsc.services.financialSystem")]
public interface IServicioCuentas
{
    [OperationContract]
    InfoResponse crearCuentaPorCobrar(crearCuentaPorCobrarRq crearCuentaPorCobrarRq);
}
```

Comment: `[DataContract(Namespace = "")]` controls the namespace of all elements created for that contract.  The namespace of the parent element (`<crearCuentaPorCobrarRq>`) is controlled by the namespace of the *outer element's contract*.  Can you show the entire XML including the root element?  See also [Adding a DataMember to a different namespace to the DataContract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705742/).

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://com.lsc">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <com:crearCuentaPorCobrar>
         <com:crearCuentaPorCobrarRq>
            <infoRequest>
               <RequestID></RequestID>
            </infoRequest>
            <cuentasCobrar>
               <CuentaCobrar>                  
                  <dias></dias>
               </CuentaCobrar>
            </cuentasCobrar>
         </com:crearCuentaPorCobrarRq>
      </com:crearCuentaPorCobrar>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: You mean, it's contained by a class implementing `MessageContract`?  If so, can you include that class in your question?

Comment: crearCuentaPorCobrar is an OperationContract method that is declared in a ServiceContract called: that has a namespace "http://com.lsc".
The idea is that crearCuentaPorCobrar maintains the prefix com but its parameters crearCuentaPorCobrarRq in the OperationContract changes.

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://com.lsc.services.financialSystem")]
    public interface IServicioCuentas
    {
[OperationContract]
InfoResponse crearCuentaPorCobrar(crearCuentaPorCobrarRq crearCuentaPorCobrarRq); 
}

Comment: crearCuentaPorCobrar is an OperationContract method that is declared in a ServiceContract called: that has a namespace "http://com.lsc".
The idea is that crearCuentaPorCobrar maintains the prefix com but its parameters crearCuentaPorCobrarRq in the OperationContract changes.

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://com.lsc.services.financialSystem")]
    public interface IServicioCuentas
    {
[OperationContract]
InfoResponse crearCuentaPorCobrar(crearCuentaPorCobrarRq crearCuentaPorCobrarRq); 
}