# Serialize/deserialize objects - order of fields matters?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

Is it possible that `DataContractSerializer` wrongly deserializes an object if the fields are not in the "correct" (whatever that means) order?

The classes that I try to serialize/deserialize do not have order-attributes placed on fields/properties. Yet one of my fields always gets deserialized as `null` even though it has a non-null value (it actually contains a list of strings).

When I moved two XML elements in serialized file around to match the order in another XML example (for which deserialization worked without problems) everything started to work.

This makes no sense to me but maybe someone knows better. ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To be eligible for correct serialization / serialization by the `DataContractSerializer`, all of the following must be true.

1. The class that must be serialized must have `SerializableAttribute` or `DataContractAttribute` set;
2. The properties and fields of the class that must be serialized require the `DataMemberAttribute` set;
3. The datatype of the serializable property or field must be serializable (i.e., have a public ctor and inherit ISerializable);
4. The class that must be serialized must implement `IExtensibleDataObject`;
5. Note: serializable fields can be either public or private.
6. **[Members must be in alphabetical order](http://theburningmonk.com/2010/08/wcf-be-ware-of-the-field-ordering-when-using-datacontractserializer/) or you should use the [`Order`-property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.order.aspx) of the `DataMemberAttribute`.**

So, the order of the declaration *does* matter. If members are not in alphabetical order, they are skipped. Look up [this answer at StackOverflow for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519240/wcf-datacontract-some-fields-do-not-deserialize), perhaps it applies to your case.

Comment: As of .NET 3.5 SP1, the first and the second rules can be omitted.

Comment: @Martin: r u sure? For instance, for web services, which require serializability, they require `DataMemberAttribute` still, even in .NET 4.0. Do you have a link to a reference? I'd be interested to read more on that (and then update my answer).

Comment: Link in rule 6 is dead

Comment: @bkribbs, thank, I have located a different link with similar content, apparently, that site went dead.