# Does the structure of a C# file affect what is compiled?

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, file-structure

Does the structure of a C# file affect what is compiled?

For example, would the order of members (in terms of where in the file it exists) affect the compiled class?

Comment: Why not just try it out?

Comment: ...and tell us what you found out?

Comment: ...and use different compilers to cross compare. And then write a nice blog post about it and get famous instantly :)

Comment: No, AFAIK. C does, C++ sometimes does, C# not. Anyway you can check the real code statement using .NET Reflector decompiler.

Comment: Isn't it the C# file that's compiled, so you're asking if the file effects the file. :P

Comment: BigYellowCactus, I have for a small class with a few members and found nothing, but that doesn't prove that it doesn't have an affect.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Yes, my grammar is slightly ambiguous in the first paragraph, but I do mean the resulting compiled IL :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to a blog entry from Eric Lippert I read the other day, the compiler does not guarantee two compilations of the same source to end up the same IL. This wasn't about method ordering, though, but I think that applies too - so, I don't think it is safe to assume any method ordering in the compiled class. I also wouldn't expect any connection between source file method ordering and IL method ordering.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/05/31/past-performance-is-no-guarantee-of-future-results.aspx is a link to the blog.

Answer (score 2):

While in most cases the order is unimportant, this is **not** the case with anonymous types:

```
new{a=1,b=2}
```

creates a different, incompatible type to

```
new{b=2,a=1}
```

Comment: Do you know of any cases other than serialisation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282991/serialize-deserialize-objects-order-of-fields-matters), where the order is important?

Answer (score 0):

there is no guarantee for the order of the members.

Comment: Are you sure that's correct (member names not being the same)? When using something like reflection or ILSpy you can see they are unchanged.

Comment: I'm with you, @GeorgeDuckett.