# Deserializing XML with unknown element order

Tags: c#, serialization, soap, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I'm trying to implement a client for a service with a really deficient spec.  It's SOAP-like, although it has no WSDL or equivalent file.  The spec also doesn't provide any information about the correct ordering of elements - they're listed alphabetically in the spec, but the service returns an XML parse error if they're out of order in the request (said order to be derived by examining the examples).

I can *work* with this for submitting requests, even if it's a pain.  However, I don't know how to handle responses correctly.

With both `SoapEnvelope` and directly with `XmlSerializer`, if the response contains an element I haven't yet ordered correctly, it shows up as `null` on my object.  Once again, I can manage to work with this, and manually order the class properties [with `Order` attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282991/serialize-deserialize-objects-order-of-fields-matters), but I have no way to tell whether the original XML has a field that I didn't order correctly and thus got left as `null`.

This leads me to the current question:  **How can I check if the XmlSerializer dropped a field**?

Comment: I'm really hoping this is actually an X-Y problem, and there's a simpler answer than checking up on the XmlSerializer, but I'm not expecting one.

Comment: You can use [`XmlSerializer.UnknownElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.unknownelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @dbc - Oooh, that could work.  It's not ideal, but I can definitely work with it.  Of course, nothing about this situation is ideal, so I shouldn't be surprised.

Comment: @dbc - Actually, before you go and turn that into an answer, is there a way to do that as part of the `SoapEnvelope.GetBodyObject()` call, or do I need to use the XmlSerializer directly?

Comment: Just to be sure I understand: when serializing, you want to set [`XmlElementAttribute.Order`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.order%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`XmlArrayAttribute.Order`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute.order%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for each property in your types, but when deserializing, you want to ignore the order and deserialize elements in any order?

Comment: @dbc - Yes, that would be best.  Alternatively, I need to at least log a warning somewhere that I ignored a field (which is what UnknownElement helps with).  Because I only know the correct ordering of a subset of all possible fields in the reply. So I can manually specify the order for those fields, but I need to know that I need to go add support for any fields that I missed.

Comment: By `SoapEnvelope.GetBodyObject()` do you mean [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa748457.aspx) from [Web Service Enhancements 3.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139626.aspx)?  I've never used that before.

Comment: @dbc - Yes.  I'm only using it for that class, so I forgot it wasn't part of the standard set of .NET libraries.  It's fine if you don't have an answer that uses that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`XmlSerializer.UnknownElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.unknownelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event on `XmlSerializer` to capture out-of-order elements.  This will allow you to manually find and fix problems in deserialization.

A more complex answer would be to correctly order your elements when serializing, but ignore order when deserializing.  This requires using the [`XmlAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and the [`XmlSerializer(Type, XmlAttributeOverrides)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfaxz1a0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor.  Note that serializers constructed in this manner [*must be cached in a hash table and resused*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to avoid a severe memory leak, and thus this solution is a little "finicky" since Microsoft doesn't provide a meaningful [`GetHashCode()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlAttributes.cs) for [`XmlAttributeOverrides`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfaxz1a0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  The following is one possible implementation which depends upon knowing in advance all types that need their [`XmlElementAttribute.Order`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.order%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`XmlArrayAttribute.Order`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute.order%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties ignored, thus avoiding the need to create a complex custom hashing method:

```
 // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506708/deserializing-xml-with-unknown-element-order
public class XmlSerializerFactory : XmlOrderFreeSerializerFactory
{
    static readonly XmlSerializerFactory instance;

    // Use a static constructor for lazy initialization.
    private XmlSerializerFactory()
        : base(new[] { typeof(Type2), typeof(Type1), typeof(TestClass), typeof(Type3) }) // These are the types in your client for which Order needs to be ignored whend deserializing
    {
    }

    static XmlSerializerFactory()
    {
        instance = new XmlSerializerFactory();
    }

    public static XmlSerializerFactory Instance { get { return instance; } }
}

public abstract class XmlOrderFreeSerializerFactory
{
    readonly XmlAttributeOverrides overrides;
    readonly object locker = new object();
    readonly Dictionary<Type, XmlSerializer> serializers = new Dictionary<Type, XmlSerializer>();

    static void AddOverrideAttributes(Type type, XmlAttributeOverrides overrides)
    {
        if (type == null || type == typeof(object) || type.IsPrimitive || type == typeof(string))
            return;

        var mask = BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;
        foreach (var member in type.GetProperties(mask).Cast<MemberInfo>().Union(type.GetFields(mask)))
        {
            XmlAttributes overrideAttr = null;
            foreach (var attr in member.GetCustomAttributes<XmlElementAttribute>())
            {
                overrideAttr = overrideAttr ?? new XmlAttributes();
                overrideAttr.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute { DataType = attr.DataType, ElementName = attr.ElementName, Form = attr.Form, IsNullable = attr.IsNullable, Namespace = attr.Namespace, Type = attr.Type });
            }
            foreach (var attr in member.GetCustomAttributes<XmlArrayAttribute>())
            {
                overrideAttr = overrideAttr ?? new XmlAttributes();
                overrideAttr.XmlArray = new XmlArrayAttribute { ElementName = attr.ElementName, Form = attr.Form, IsNullable = attr.IsNullable, Namespace = attr.Namespace };
            }
            foreach (var attr in member.GetCustomAttributes<XmlArrayItemAttribute>())
            {
                overrideAttr = overrideAttr ?? new XmlAttributes();
                overrideAttr.XmlArrayItems.Add(attr);
            }
            foreach (var attr in member.GetCustomAttributes<XmlAnyElementAttribute>())
            {
                overrideAttr = overrideAttr ?? new XmlAttributes();
                overrideAttr.XmlAnyElements.Add(new XmlAnyElementAttribute { Name = attr.Name, Namespace = attr.Namespace });
            }
            if (overrideAttr != null)
                overrides.Add(type, member.Name, overrideAttr);
        }
    }

    protected XmlOrderFreeSerializerFactory(IEnumerable<Type> types)
    {
        overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        foreach (var type in types.SelectMany(t => t.BaseTypesAndSelf()).Distinct())
        {
            AddOverrideAttributes(type, overrides);
        }
    }

    public XmlSerializer GetSerializer(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        lock (locker)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer;
            if (!serializers.TryGetValue(type, out serializer))
                serializers[type] = serializer = new XmlSerializer(type, overrides);
            return serializer;
        }
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        while (type != null)
        {
            yield return type;
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
    }
}
```

Then when deserializing a type, use the `XmlSerializer` provided by the factory.  Given that [`SoapEnvelope`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Web.Services3.SoapEnvelope.aspx) is a subclass of `XmlDocument`, you should be able to deserialize the body node along the lines of the answer in [Deserialize object property with StringReader vs XmlNodeReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102275/deserialize-object-property-with-stringreader-vs-xmlnodereader).

Note -- only moderately tested.  Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/680klb).