# How to override XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute with XmlAttributes in dotnet core

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, xml-serialization

I have to implement a SOAP call with a JSON object that comes from our frontend which is obtained by a JSON Schema that is translated from an XSD schema of a SOAP service.
We have already implemented a translation between this JSON we receive and the corresponding XML and we are able to serialize and deserialize c# class of this SOAP service.

The main problem that we are now facing is that the JSON properties are not fixed in order, but the SOAP class have a defined order and the XML tag that don't comes in the right position are not serialized. I have tried to implement this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506708/deserializing-xml-with-unknown-element-order/33508815#33508815) in order to override the default `XmlElement` attributes that comes to the SOAP reference and for some classes this is working well.

Unfortunately, we are unable to create an `XmlSerializer` for types that have at last one property with the `XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute` defined, like this one:

```
public partial class CUAA
{
    
    private string itemField;
    
    private ItemChoiceType itemElementNameField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PersonaFisica", typeof(string), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PersonaGiuridica", typeof(string), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemElementName")]
    public string Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemChoiceType ItemElementName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemElementNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemElementNameField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

If we try to use override for a class that contains this attribute we got this error:

`You need to add XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute to the 'Item' member`

I have looked inside `XmlAttributes` class [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes?view=net-5.0), I've found that the class have a property `XmlChoiceIdentifier` that could contains the attribute but it's a read-only prop and seems to me that this prop is always `null`.

**There is any way to make this override work, or to add this attribute to the override?**

Comment: Just curious, have you solved this? I'm having the same kind of problem and found no solution yet.