# HttpClient ReadAsAsync<Type> only deserializing part of the response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xml-deserialization, dotnet-httpclient, mediatypeformatter

I am using the following to make a call to a WebAPI

```
using (HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.Create(new AuthorisationHandler()))
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseURI);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

    var httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsXmlAsync<AvailRequest>("Avail/Search/", req);
    httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var availResp = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<AvailResponse>();
    return availResp;
}
```

the AvailResponse class looks something like this

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class AvailResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public ICollection<NotWorkingType> NotWorking { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ICollection<WorkingType> Working { get; set; }
}
```

for some reason - clearly unknown to me - when the response comes in and is parsed into the `AvailResponse` object only the `WorkingType` is de-serialised and the other `NotWorking` one is not. I have used fiddler and can confirm that the response has both these in i.
I have tried using a `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` in place of the default and even setting the `UseXmlSerialiser` to true, but to no avail.
could someone shed some light on what is going on please
I would have thought that if it is not going to deserialise properly it would chuck and error rather than simply deserialising a part of the response.

any help as ever much appreciated

thanks

nat

Comment: Just in case this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519240/wcf-datacontract-some-fields-do-not-deserialize

Comment: hi jason thanks for that, presume i need to do that all the way down the hierarchy? as done the top few but still no luck.. :(

Comment: Sorry that didn't work for you. I'm not sure what the explanation for your issue is exactly, I thought I'd give that link a shot :)

Comment: thanks jason, appreciate your help nonetheless