# ReadAsAsync Class using XmlMediaTypeFormatter or other Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to deserialize the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jobInfo
   xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
    <id>asjdkfljasl;kdf</id>
    <operation>query</operation>
    <object>jsdkfjsakldjakl</object>
    ...
</jobInfo>
```

I have the following code that makes the POST request and works successfully, but cannot deserialize into my class.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-SFDC-Session", binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId);

var content = new StringContent(createJobXml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
    $"https://{SERVER_INSTANCE}.salesforce.com/services/async/43.0/job", content
);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

jobInfo job = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<jobInfo >(new List<MediaTypeFormatter>() {
    new XmlMediaTypeFormatter { UseXmlSerializer = true },
    new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()
});
```

But I get the error

> No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'jobInfo ' from content with media type 'application/xml',

my jobInfo was generated using `xsd.exe doc.xml`, `xsd.exe doc.xsd /classes`

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.81.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class jobInfo
{
    private string idField;
    private string operationField;
    private string objectField;
    ...
    public string id
    {
        get {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }
    public string operation
    {
        get {
            return this.operationField;
        }
        set {
            this.operationField = value;
        }
    }
    ...
 }
```

**What am I missing in order to deserialize this correctly?**

This suggests that I should just read it as a string:

[How to use HttpClient to read an XML response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942486/how-to-use-httpclient-to-read-an-xml-response)

but this suggests that it should "just work"

[HttpClient ReadAsAsync<Type> only deserializing part of the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428974/httpclient-readasasynctype-only-deserializing-part-of-the-response)

I have also tried (was using class Bulkv1Job before I used xsd to convert the xml to a class)

```
[DataContract]
public class Bulkv1Job
{
    [DataMember]
    string id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    string operation { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    string @object { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and

```
[XmlRoot("jobInfo")]
public class Bulkv1Job
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    string id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("operation")]
    string operation { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why are the properties listed as private? It looks like you manually added these values.  The names also do not match the xml tag names.

Comment: I'm not sure, it's what xsd.exe spit out, for that particular class. I have added the other two "classes" I have tried (see `Bulkv1Job`). I think the error is specifically because of `application/xml`, not so much how I have the class set up, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You should probably make sure standard XML serialization and deserialization work in unit tests first, to make sure that works before `ReadAsAsync`

Comment: @jdweng I did not include the public fields, they're added now.

Comment: @Ryan that helped me find my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing with

```
var s = await response.content.readasstringasync();
var buffer = encoding.utf8.getbytes(s);
using (var stream = new memorystream(buffer)) {
    var serializer = new xmlserializer(typeof(jobinfo)); // FAILED LINE
    var jobinfo = (jobinfo)serializer.deserialize(stream);
    //then do whatever you want
    return jobinfo;
}
```

I found that the serializer failed on the above line due to a class protection error.
Ensuring the `jobInfo` class was public and accessible, the error went away and the `deserialize(stream)` worked.

Removing that code and using `readAsAsync<jobInfo>(...)` worked appropriately afterwards.

Thanks @Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm I'm not an expert with soap but it should have decorators like [DataMember] on your properties and [DataContract(NameSpace="jobInfo")] on your class if I remember well.
You can see that in the first suggestion you provide the guy use [XmlRoot] and [XmlElement]

You can also see [WCF Datacontract, some fields do not deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519240/wcf-datacontract-some-fields-do-not-deserialize) , maybe it would help you